# Pandas extract word from link domain

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd    
d = {'domain': ['linkedin.com','aumniversal.tumblr.com','plasticdrea.ms','linkedin.com','s-lw.tumblr.com','newsonline.media','creshendo.co.vu','deadly-skz-gods-cb.tumblr.com','deo.progr.am']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

I want to extract the words before the last word (for example, before .com, but I have not only .com there). So it will be:

```
    domain                            words
0   linkedin.com                    linkedin
1   aumniversal.tumblr.com          tumblr
2   plasticdrea.ms                  plasticdrea
3   linkedin.com                    linkedin
4   s-lw.tumblr.com                 tumblr
5   newsonline.media                newsonline
6   creshendo.co.vu                 co
7   deadly-skz-gods-cb.tumblr.com   tumblr
8   deo.progr.am                    progr
```

Comment: I guess you want to capture the domain name here. You have wrong domain captured for #6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
df['words'] = df['domain'].str.extract(r'([^.]+)\.[^.]*$')
```

output:

```
                          domain        words
0                   linkedin.com     linkedin
1         aumniversal.tumblr.com       tumblr
2                 plasticdrea.ms  plasticdrea
3                   linkedin.com     linkedin
4                s-lw.tumblr.com       tumblr
5               newsonline.media   newsonline
6                creshendo.co.vu           co
7  deadly-skz-gods-cb.tumblr.com       tumblr
8                   deo.progr.am        progr
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Buc9L/1)

```
([^.]+)   # capture word
\.[^.]*   # followed by .xxx
$         # and end of line
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and select previous last value  by indexing:

```
df['words'] = df['domain'].str.split('\.').str[-2]
print (df)
                          domain        words
0                   linkedin.com     linkedin
1         aumniversal.tumblr.com       tumblr
2                 plasticdrea.ms  plasticdrea
3                   linkedin.com     linkedin
4                s-lw.tumblr.com       tumblr
5               newsonline.media   newsonline
6                creshendo.co.vu           co
7  deadly-skz-gods-cb.tumblr.com       tumblr
8                   deo.progr.am        progr
```